# Remove LI from nested list preserve children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested UL LI list. e.g.

BEFORE

```
<ul>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B
        <ul>
            <li id="removeme">Item BA (REMOVE ME)
            <ul>
                <li>Item BAA</li>
                <li>Item BAB</li>
                <li>Item BAC</li>
                <li>Item BAD
                    <ul>
                    <li>Item BADA</li>
                    <li>Item BADB</li>
                    <li>Item BADC</li>
                    <li>Item BADD</li>
                    </ul>                 
                </li>
                <li>Item</li>
            </ul>            
            </li>
            <li>Item BB</li>
            <li>Item BC </li>
            <li>Item BD</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item C</li>
    <li>Item D</li>
    <li>Item E</li>
</ul>
```

AFTER :

```
<ul>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B
        <ul>
            <li>Item BAA</li>
            <li>Item BAB</li>
            <li>Item BAC</li>
            <li>Item BAD
                <ul>
                <li>Item BADA</li>
                <li>Item BADB</li>
                <li>Item BADC</li>
                <li>Item BADD</li>
                </ul>                 
            </li>
            <li>Item</li>           
            </li>
            <li>Item BB</li>
            <li>Item BC </li>
            <li>Item BD</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item C</li>
    <li>Item D</li>
    <li>Item E</li>
</ul>
```

If i wanted to remove the item above in the brackets (or anyitem) by double clicking it for example and remove it from the list however preserving the children elements and re-parenting them.  how would you do this?  i am working on a navigation manager and need to be able to delete items but not the children and have them re-parented.

Any cluees would be great.

I've though about getting all children of current element the append to current items parent. But that would duplicate the ul.

Thanks

*UPDATED TO INCLUDE BEFORE AND AFTER EXAMPLES

Comment: Along with what Explosion Pills said, "re-parenting" is unclear to me - could you provide an example of what you would like your html structure to look like after you do work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target element that you want to do this operation on is `elem`, then you can do this:

```
$(elem).find("li").insertAfter(elem);
$(elem).remove();
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RrHB2/

To hook this up to a dlbclick event, it would look something like this (where you fill in the appropriate selector to target the right items):

```
$(selector).dblclick(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var target = $(this);
    target.find("li").insertAfter(item);
    target.remove();
});
```

---

If you want to support multiple levels and only collapse one level, then you could use this:

```
var target = $("#removeme");
target.children("ul").children().insertAfter(target);
target.remove();
```

or

```
$(selector).dblclick(function() {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var target = $(this);
    target.children("ul").children().insertAfter(target);
    target.remove();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TbDY7/

Comment: this works great for a single nested UL, however if there are move levels underneath they get removed into a single level also.

Comment: @user257503 - OK, I added a second example to my answer that preserves nested items.  I didn't know you needed to work with multiple levels.

Comment: Thanks for this..let me test in my main example then i will be back in literally 5 min.  Really is annoying when you find something this simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$("li").dblclick(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $children = $(this).children().detach();
    $(this).remove();
    // do something with $children here, e.g.,
    // $children.appendTo(someOtherElement)
});
```

The [`.detach()` method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) removes the elements from the DOM but keeps all jQuery data associated with them, so you can re-insert them later.

Of course you'd need to declare the `$children` variable outside the click handler if you intend to use it at some point after the click event (e.g., in response to some later event).

If doing this in response to a click or double-click you need to use `event.stopPropagation()` because these events propagate up through the DOM such that a click event for one of the nested li elements would otherwise propagate up to the parent li element(s) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('elem').dbclick(function(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target);
    var children = elem.children();

    for (var i = children.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
       children[i].insertAfter(elem);

     elem.remove();
 }
```